# Remove elements from an array into another array (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm new here and new to coding and I can use some help with a problem I'm trying to solve.
I'm trying to remove all integers that are less than 5 from array
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and put them into a new array b = [], and then print out the b array.
I've done many Google searches but I can't find anything that helps.
I'm starting to think this is not possible.

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = a.select { |i| i < 5 } # [1, 2, 3, 4]
a = a - b # [5, 6]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

```
b, a = a.partition { |i| i < 5 }
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

```
b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
a #=> [5, 6]
```

See [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

Answer (score 1):

To actually remove elements from `a` while putting them in an existing array `b`, you could use [`reject!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#reject-21-method):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = []

a.reject! { |i| b << i if i < 5 }

a #=> [5, 6]
b #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If `i < 5` evaluates to true, `b << i` puts that element in `b` and returns a *truthy* result which causes `reject!` to remove it from `a`.

Likewise, if `i < 5` evaluates to false, `b << i` is skipped, the block returns a *falsy* result and that element remains in `a`.